# awk select part of column (3rd of 3 characters)

Tags: awk

I have a number of files where I select some columns with the following

```
cat test.txt | awk ' {
if ($11 ~ /229/ && $5 ~ /1A1/) 
{print $0, ($3 + 1) }         
if ($11 ~ /229/ && $5 ~ /1A2/) 
{print $0, ($3 - 1) }
if ($11 ~ /49/ && $5 ~ /1A1/)  
{print $0, ($3 - 1)}
if ($11 ~ /49/ && $5 ~ /1A2/)
{print $0, ($3 + 1) }
}' > output
```

The problem is that some files might have different letter for `1A1` or `1A2` such as `1K1`, `1K2`..... 
I would like to make the condition  `$5 ~(/1A2/) or  $5 ~(/1A1/)` more "general" and I tried things like

```
$5 ~(/??1/)
$5 ~(/??2/)
```

So far no success. Can anyone help me on that?
Please note that I need to keep also the selection criteria in $11

```
cat test.txt | awk ' {
    if ($11 ~ /229/ && $5 ~ /??1/)
....
```

Comment: Do you mean for `$11 ~ /49/` to match when `$11` is `53249436`, for example? If you post concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you create a concise, robust solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with regular expressions, in this case you can use this simple `awk` program:

```
awk ' {
if ($11 ~ /(229|49)/ && $5 ~ /1[A-Z][1-2]/) 
{print $0, ($3 + 1) }}' test.txt > output
```

I'm assuming that:

- Second character in `$5` is any Capital/Mayus Letter(`[A-Z]`),
- Third character in `$5` is `1` or `2`(`[1-2]`)
- `$11` only can be `229` or `49`